# Proving that periodic function (except constant function) can not be an algebraic function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, periodic-functions

**Definition:** A function $f(x)$ is said to be algebraic if it satisfies the following equation in $y$: 
$y^m+R_1(x)y^{m-1}+R_2(x)y^{m-2}+\cdots+R_{m-1}y+R_m(x)=0$, where $R_i(x)'s$ are rational functions i.e. of the form $\frac {p(x)}{q(x)}$, where $p(x),q(x)\ne 0  \forall x\in \mathbb R$ are polynomial functions. $\tag 1$

Let $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a function (non -constant) that has period $T$ i.e., $g(x)=g(x+T)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

How do I prove that $y=g(x)$ can't be a root of the equation of the form $(1)$?

I'm trying to prove by contradiction: WLOG Let $y=g(x)$ be a root of equation $(1)$. Let $g(1)=c$, then 
$(g(x))^m+R_1(x)(g(x))^{m-1}+R_2(x)(g(x))^{m-2}+\cdots+R_{m-1}g(x)+R_m(x)=0$ will have infinitely many roots? $x=1,1+T,1+2T,\cdots $etc. How do I take it from here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $F(x,y)=g(x)^m+R_1(y)g(x)^{m-1}+\ldots+R_{m-1}(y)g(x)+R_m(y)$. We know that for each $x$, $F(x,x)=0$. As $g$ is $T$-periodic, for each real number $x$ and each integer $n$, $F(x,x+nT)=F(x+nT,x+nT)=0$.
Now, for any given $x$, $F(x,\cdot)$ is a rational function, and has every $x+nT$ as its roots. So it has infinitely many roots so is zero.
Thus $F=0$.
In other words, let $y$ be any real number, then every element $z \in g(\mathbb{R})$ is a root of the polynomial $Z^m+\sum_{i=1}^m{R_i(y)Z^{m-i}}$. It follows that $g(\mathbb{R})$ is finite -- in particular, if $g$ is continuous, then $g$ is constant.

Note that not much more can be said. For instance, we can write $z(z-1)(z-y)=z^3+R_1(y)z^2+R_2(y)z+R_3(y)$ for some $R_1,R_2,R_3$, and it's not too hard to see that if $g(x)=1(x \in \mathbb{Q})$ (or any other periodic function with values in $\{0,1\}$), $g(x)^3+R_1(y)g(x)^2+R_2(y)g(x)+R_3(y)$ is always zero, that $g$ is periodic nonconstant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response :).  Can you please explain $g(x)$ in last para? I am confused by "periodic functions with values in $\{0,1\}"$.

Comment: My example is the function $g$ defined by $g(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational and zero otherwise. But any other periodic function $h$ would work, as long as for each $x$, $h(x)$ is either zero or one.

Comment: Is it correct to say that: As shown above, if there are infinitely many values in range of a periodic function then it can't be algebraic. Therefore, floor function can't be algebraic and nor can fraction part function. However, $x=floor (x)+\{x\}$ is algebraic showing that sum of transcendental functions may not be transcendental?

Comment: The floor function isn’t periodic, but apart from that, yes?

Comment: I meant that floor function is periodic non-constant. Right? And proof above also nicely shows that Dirichlet function (assumes 1 when its argument is rational and 0 else) is algebraic. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: No, the floor function still isn’t periodic. There is no $T>0$ such that for any real number $x$, $floor(x+T)=floor(x)$, because the floor function goes to $\infty$ at $\infty$.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. And am I right about the Dirichlet function? Thanks.

Comment: Yes about the Dirichlet function.

Comment: I request one clarification please: chapter 9, page number 218 of Terrence Tao's Analysis 1 calls Dirichlet function as not algebraic.  The text says "This function is not algebraic (i.e. it cannot be expressed in terms of x purely by using the standard algebraic operations of +,− , square root, division etc.; we will not need this notion in this text".  So I think that the definition used by us, is more general as not every algebraic function can be expressed using $x$ by finitely many algebraic operations. Is my understanding correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The definition of algebraic function we used in this question is much more general than the one used by Tao.

Comment: Thank you so much :).